# Possible misspeling of 音葉?

Tags: words, spelling

I encountered follwoing sentence

> という音葉は胸にしまっておく。

And I think that 葉 is probably just misspelling, i.e. は entered twice instead of once. But I'm not sure. Can someone help?

Comment: It's probably a typo for 言葉 ("**k**otoba"). 言葉 (kotoba) and 音葉 (otoba?) are similar both in romaji and in kanji, and 言葉を胸にしまう is a common phrase.

Comment: Thanks. If this is common expression what is it meaning?

Comment: "To leave it unsaid."